# Table not loaded with angular data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load a html table with Sql data using datatable and angular js on onchange() event. Sql Data is loaded in DataTable but when I return data table as json the Html table is not loaded with data.

Below Is my Action Result:

```
public ActionResult getBychqIdForCheque(string custname)
 {
  DataTable dt = objemp.ChqIssueBs.getChqIssueDetail(custname);
  if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
   {
    return Json(dt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
  else
   {
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   }
```

Below Is my Angular Code:

```
app.factory('crudServiceUser', function ($http) {
    crudUserObj = {};
       crudUserObj.GetByEidForChq = function (eid) {
        var Emp;
        Emp = $http(
            {
                method: 'Get',
                url: '/Employee/ChequeIssue/getBychqIdForCheque',
                params: { custname: eid }
            }
            ).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        return Emp;
    }         
   return crudUserObj;
});


app.controller('usersController', function ($scope, crudServiceUser) {
  $scope.getbyeidforchq = function (eid) {
   crudServiceUser.GetByEidForChq(eid).then(function (result) {     
            $scope.Cheque = result;
        })
    }
```

And Below My View:

```
<td ng-controller="usersController">
 <input type="text" ng-model="custname", ng-change = "getbyeidforchq(custname)" name="txtSearch" />
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Cheque Number</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Cheque Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="cheqs in Cheque">
                    <td> {{cheqs.chqNo}} </td>
                    <td> {{cheqs.custName}} </td>
                    <td> {{cheqs.status}} </td>    
                </tr>
```

Comment: What error you getting

Comment: No errors but table is not loading with data

Comment: Create fiddle or plnkr with JSON that you are getting in `$scope.Cheque`. it will be helpful to look into the issue

Answer (score 0):

A CRUD API for many MySQL Systems, and others in the future

Single file PHP 5.6 script that adds a REST API to a MySQL 5.6 InnoDB, MariaDB databases.

Requirements
PHP 5.6 or higher with PDO drivers for MySQL, PgSQL, Oracle or SqlSrv enabled

[Transaction_CRUD_API](https://github.com/shangab/transaction_crud_api)